# NSJSONSerialization - key names from array

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am parsing JSON data using objective-c.

The data is as follows:

{"parcels":{"12595884967":{"kj_number":"KJ6612636902","recipient":"Krzysztof Racki","courier":"3"}}}

I have an object "parcels" which has keys for packages. Now while I dont have a problem extracting this using JSONSerialization class, I am stuck figuring how to get a key name (i mean, how to read value 12595884967 from code).

Code:

```
  if ( [ NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonObject ] ) {

    // we are getting root element, the "parcels"
    NSMutableSet* parcels = [ jsonObject mutableSetValueForKey:@"parcels" ];

    // get array of NSDictionary*'ies 
    // in this example array has single NSDictionary* element with flds like "kj_number"
    NSArray* array = [ parcels allObjects ];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < [ array count ] ; ++i ) {

        NSObject* obj = [ array objectAtIndex: i ];

        // the problem: how i get this dictionary KEY? string value of 12595884967
        // how I should get it from code here?
        // like: number = [ obj name ] or maybe [ obj keyName ]

        if ( [ obj isKindOfClass:[ NSDictionary class ] ] ) {
           // this always evaluates to true
           // here we do reading attributes like kj_number, recipient etc
           // and this works
        }

    }
  }
```

for example in java it was:

```
                JSONObject json = response.asJSONObject();
        JSONObject parcels = json.getJSONObject( "parcels" );

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Iterator<String> it = parcels.keys();

        while ( it.hasNext() ) {                    

          String key = it.next(); // value of 12595884967
                  Object value = parcel.getObject( key ); // JSONObject ref with data

                }
```

Answer (score 3):

A set doesn't store keys. You want to get a dictionary from the json.

```
NSDictionary* parcels = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"parcels"];

// get the keys
NSArray *keys = [parcels allKeys];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSDictionary *parcel = [parcels objectForKey:key];
    // do something with parcel
}
```

Getting the keys in an array first is optional, you could iterate over the parcels dictionary directly: `for (NSString *key in parcels) {`.

Comment: Hello. You have directed me in correct way, thank you :)

The problem was that I was parsing JSON using following line: <code> NSJSONSerialization* jsonObject = [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:nsData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil ]; </code>

Comment: and that I was not allowed to get "parcels" as dictionary because there was no selector blah blah blah. Apparently, changing it to NSDictionary* solves the problem, though I dont really know why it works (I tried to initialize new NSDictionary* value as = jsonObject (of type NSJSONSerialization) but they are not assigment-compaitible so I am not sure if NSJSONSerialization is subclass of NSDictionary or why this does work at all. Anyway it works thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to use a `NSDictionary` instead of `NSMutableSet`.
The `NSDictionary` has a method `allKeys` that will provide you with the requested data.

Comment: thank you anyway. i just didnt know that result of " [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:nsData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil ]; " could be casted to NSDictionary* and work